# How to make Parent container should contain all children side by side

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to make a horizontal image slider. Lets say there are 6 total images and 3 are displayed at a time. So the width of outer div should be width of 3 images and width of inner div is equal to 6 images so that it can be scrolled using JavaScript, but size of inner div is equal to outer div only.

```css
.image_slider {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline;
}

.image_wrapper>img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_slider">
  <div class="image_wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akmittal/pu7rxujv/)

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `width:auto`,`max-width:100%`, and `white-space:nowrap` on `.image_slider`.

`.image_wrapper` should be set to `width:auto` and `position:absolute`

```
    <style>
        .image_slider {
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: auto;
            max-width:100%;
            position: relative;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .image_wrapper{
            width:auto;
            position:absolute;
        }
        .image_wrapper > img {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="image_slider">
       <div class="image_wrapper">
        <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: images are still not available inline and a scrollbar is visible. I dont want a scrollbar. I hant to scroll on event(left and right arrows)

Comment: @Amit sorry, didn't realize you didn't want a scrollbar. I just updated the answer. See if this works.

Comment: you solution helped display images inline. But i wasnot alse to able to scroll using javascript. So i added .image_wrapper with width:auto and position:absolute now works fine. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Amit alright, updated the answer for future references :)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the width of img wrapper dynamically with jquery and achieve what you want like below

```js
var width = 0;
$('img').each(function() {
  width += $(this).outerWidth();
});
$('.wrapper').width(width + 100);
```

```css
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  background: red;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.360fashion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
  </div>


</div>
```